# Java - Name a variable with an int

Tags: java

Basically, I want to name the variable the letter "f" and the number represented by the variable "i." However, I have no idea how to do it.

```
int n = 2;
    for(int i = 0; i < generations; i++){
        creature[] f;
        fi = new creature[n];
        n = 2*n;
    }
```

As you can see above, it says "fi." I know this will not work; this is just to demonstrate what I mean. For example, the first arraylist would be "f0," the second "f1," the third "f2," and so on.
Any help to make this work would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: **Why** do you want to do this ? An array is clean and efficient.

Comment: You want a nested ArrayList.

Comment: Why you want to create so much of redundant variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading your code doesn't help me, but your description sounds like you want to use a two dimensional array:

```
int n = 2;
Creature[][] f = new Creature[generations][];
for(int i = 0; i < generations; i++){
    f[i] = new Creature[n];
    n = 2*n;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
Creature[] generation0 = f[0];
```

Comment: so, like an array with arrays in it? As in: "Yo dawg, I heard you like arrays, so I put an array in your array so you can organize while you organize?"

Comment: Yes, a two dimensional array is basically an array containing arrays. A three dimensional array is an array containing arrays which contain arrays. The number of dimensions has no upper bound.

Answer (score 4):

You could have int array and you can use like bellow . Your way is not possible in java

```
   creature[][] f = new creature[size][];
   f[i] = new creature[n];
```

Answer (score 0):

Even while you could use reflection to get variables by name, this wouldn't be clean nor efficient.

Standard ways to access values by name or number are :

- an array declared as `Creature[] f = new Creature[generations];` : you access `f[i]`
- a map declared as `Map<int, Creature> = new HashMap<>();` : you access `f.get(i)`

Note that I changed `creature` to `Creature` : Java best practice is to start class name with an Uppercase.